# Django form wizard quick finish button

Tags: python, django

I want to implement 2-page form using django-formtools form wizard and I want to add quick finish button in the first page, so that the user won't see the second page.

I know that we can [conditionally view/skip specific steps](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps) but I haven't seen an implementation that invokes the submission.

My question is that how can I add a finish button to the first page of a 2-page form?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is?

Comment: @ygesher Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution I found: We use a form variable together with a condition dict `condition_dict={'second_page': is_quick_finish}` in `urls.py`. If the user clicks "quick finish" button in the first page, then we set the form variable `quick_finish` to `True` and pass that with the following function in `views.py`:

```
def is_quick_finish(wizard):
    cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('first_page') or {}
    res = cleaned_data.get('quick_finish')
    return not res
```